# how can i manage both databases mongodb and mysql at same application

Tags: reactjs, node.js

i want to manage database both ways so based on the skill a person who know the mySQL and a person who know the mongodb both can manage the application database

i want to add both databases in my application so it is more effiient to manage the data base more efficient ways

Comment: What have you researched till now? Elaborate your problem more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a file **mongoDBConnection.js**:

```
mongoose.connect('')
.then(sucess => {
    console.log("MongoDB Server Connected!")
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("MongoDB Server Not Connected!",error)
})
```

Step 2: Create a file **mySQLConnection.js**:

```
const mysql = require("mysql")
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "", 
user: "",      
password: "",  
database: "" 
})

con.connect((error) => {
if (!error) {
    console.log("SQL Server Connected!")
}
else {
    console.log("SQL Server Not Connected!", error)
}
})
```

Step 3: Create a file **app.js**:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
require('./mongoDBConnection.js')
require('./mySQLConnection.js')
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is Live @ PORT: ${port}`)
})
```